# How to stop VBA code from within excel converting Text to Time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have tried formatting the input fields as text but to no avail. When I step through it in the debugger it shows a double number which I presume is date conversion. I just want it to treat it as text and not convert it to a time/date.

Can somebody tell me how to prevent the conversion?

The text field has YY.MM.DD hh:mm:ss in text. I want to remove the seconds so I use:

```
Select.Value=MID(Select.Value,1,16)
```

This does not work. I have put text in the field and it does truncate the last 3 positions.

Comment: Please check the cell formatting to ensure that it is either "General" or "Formula" and not "Text" on your ref cell.

Comment: I think this is more of a question for http://www.stackoverflow.com (programming related).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VBA, try using Format:

```
Select.Value=FORMAT(Select.Value,"YY.MM.DD hh:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a single quote before the text field to force it to be considered as text.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with the time value, which affects the solutions proposed. However:

If you specifically want to do it through VBA, you can define a string variable and then pass it the time value:

```
strTextValue = cstr(format(selection.value,"YY.MM.DD HH:MM"))
```

You could also do this in the worksheet directly, for example:

```
=TEXT(range("A1"),"YY.MM.DD HH.MM"))
```